# Magento not allowing more than one function in one class?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, zend-framework

I have been building a magneto plugin, and there seems to be a problem with this class functions. Not entirely sure why the following function cause the site to go into a server error 500??

Now this class is included in the config.xml. It set up so when you click save config the function ... is called. THAT function works fine, however when i include the other two functions below the entire webpage goes to the error page when save config is clicked. ANY IDEAS!!

```
<?php
class Envato_CustomConfig_Model_Observer
{

    public function adminSystemConfigChangedSection()
    {           
        $tablename_c = Mage::getStoreConfig('customconfig_options/section_one/custom_field_one');
        $email = Mage::getStoreConfig('customconfig_options/section_two/custom_field_two');
        $days = Mage::getStoreConfig('customconfig_options/section_two/custom_field_three');

        $bind = array(
            'id'    => ' ',
            'tablename_c'   => $tablename_c,
            'email' => $email,
            'days'    => $days,
            'timeStamp' => now(),
        );

        //Open Database Conenction
        $write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");

        $query = "
        insert into Envato_CustomConfig_Job (Job_Id, tablename_colummname, email_template, days, timeStamp) 
        values (:id, :tablename_c, :email, :days, :timeStamp);
        ";

        $write->query($query, $bind);

        $res = "
        SELECT Job_Id, tablename_colummname, email_template, days  FROM Envato_CustomConfig_Job 
        WHERE tablename_colummname = :tablename_c 
        AND email_template = :email 
        AND days = :days 
        AND timeStamp =:timeStamp
        AND Job_Id != :id
        LIMIT 1;
        ";

        $result = $write->query($res, $bind);

        return Envato_CustomConfig_Model_Observer::runningJobs($result);
    }
```

When the following two fucntions below are in the class the entire page crashes.

```
        public function toDateFormat($time,$format)
    {
        $dateAndTime = $time;       
        if($format == 1)
        {
            $dateAndTime = date('M d, Y', $dateAndTime);
            return $dateAndTime;
        }elseif($format == 2)
        {
            $dateAndTime = strtotime($time);
            $dateAndTime = date('M d, Y', $dateAndTime);
            return $dateAndTime;
        }else
        {
            $dateAndTime = strtotime($time);
            return $dateAndTime;
        }
    }


    public function runningJobs($res)
    {   
        $result = $res;
        foreach($result as $record) {

            $Job_Id = $record['Job_Id'];
            $tablename_colummname = $record['tablename_colummname'];
            $days = $record['days'];
            $email_template = $record['email_template'];

            $email_Details[] = explode(".",$tablename_colummname);          
            $count = count($email_Details);

            if($count < 2)
            {
                $email_Details['2'] = time();
                $email_Details['2'] = Envato_CustomConfig_Helper_Data::toDateFormat($email_Details['2'],1);
            }
        }

        $bind = array(
            'Job_Id'    => $Job_Id,
            'tableName'   => $email_Details['0'],
            'email' => $email_Details['1'],
            'email_template' => $email_template,
            'days' => $days,
            'timeStamp' => $email_Details['2'],
        );

        //Open Database Conenction
        $write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");

        $query = "
        insert into Envato_CustomConfig_Job (Job_Id, tableName, email, email_template, days, timeStamp) 
        values (:Job_Id, :tableName, :email, :email_template, :days, :timeStamp);
        ";

        $write->query($query, $bind);

        return $bind;
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT:: I HAVE ADDED MY XML CONFIG JUST INCASE THE ERROR IS HERE?

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Envato_CustomConfig>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Envato_CustomConfig>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <admin_system_config_changed_section_customconfig_options>
                <observers>
                    <customconfig>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customconfig/observer</class>
                        <method>adminSystemConfigChangedSection</method>
                    </customconfig>
                </observers>
            </admin_system_config_changed_section_customconfig_options>
        </events>

        <helpers>
            <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Helper</class>
            </customconfig>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Model</class>
            </customconfig>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <customconfig_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Envato_CustomConfig</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customconfig_setup>
            <customconfig_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </customconfig_write>
            <customconfig_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </customconfig_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <customconfig_options>
                                            <title>Email Configuration Section</title>
                                        </customconfig_options>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: Likely a parse error in one of the other 2 functions, you would need to turn on display_errors and have a look at the specific error being generated (or use an IDE that picks up syntax errors as noted in answer below)

Comment: i have but its still not working. @JasonFingar

Comment: Getting visibility of your server error logs are probably the only way to offer further assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

Missing semicolons

```
$email_template = $record['email_template']
```

and here

```
$email_Details['2'] = Envato_CustomConfig_Helper_Data::toDateFormat($email_Details['2'],1)
```

typo here

```
$email_Details['2'] = strtotime(now());
```

Use a better IDE ;)

Comment: thank you, however it is still not working, there is a server error 500 message coming up. @tine.codes

Answer (score 0):

If you got error 500, first thing you ll have to do is check your logs. 
Have a look on /var/log, and you ll probably have errors ( i guess system.log but look at the more recent one).

Then if you bring us informations, we will be able to help you, but you ll probably even fix it yourself! :)

Comment: the error i can see is whenever the functions are included in the class. the url add " section/customconfig_options/ " to the the end so it loads the server error page. the log fileis not opening unfortuntly

Comment: well without logs, we can't help you ... so try to fix this before going further